# Why does return not work?

Tags: c++, return

I am a beginner in c++ and I am trying to write factorial using recursion.
But, somehow the `return` won't work. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int num) {
    if(num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return num * factorial(num - 1);
}

int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Please enter a number and I will do its factorial : ";
    cin >> num;
    factorial(num); 
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the `return` won't work?

By the way I am using sublime on the mac.

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash? Does it return an unexpected value?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?  Note that in `main` you don't do anything with the return value from `factorial`.

Comment: The return won't display onto the terminal.

Comment: You have to assign the returned value to a variable. Try `int ans = factorial(num);` Then `std::cout << ans << std::endl;`

Comment: @Ian You forgot the return in `main`

Comment: @Ian I did not downvote, but for future reference, try including the part "The return won't display onto the terminal" in the question. "it won't work" is not enough information for a complete question

Comment: @KABoissonneault `main` gets an implicit `return 0;` if it is left out.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was aware, but I thought OP might have wanted the result of the factorial returned from main.

Comment: Debugger.  Using a debugger is the way of knowledge.  Place your breakpoints at each `return`.  Run your program.  Then single step and discover what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return works perfectly, it's just that your code is not using it.

The call to `factorial(num)` produces no output, just the return value. If you want to see it printed, add `cout << factorial(num) << endl;`

Comment: Why `endl` instead of `'\n'`?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Because the intention is that the output be made available immediately, thus the flush.

Comment: A suggestion: don't calculate factorials like this. In case of 32 bit integers it will overflow at factorial(13).

Comment: @Hurkyl: Is it? Unlikely, before the next prompt / before exit seems more like what's needed.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It's usually my intent when doing console I/O, although I tend not to write interactive applications; in any case it's premature to try and optimize away flushes. Incidentally, if the intent is to be available before the next prompt, then not flushing is actually a *bug*, since reading from `cin` is **not** guaranteed to flush `cout`! The edge case I'm aware of is if there is still input available in `cin`'s buffer; I'm not sure if there are any others.

Comment: `main` is unique in not needing a `return` statement even though its return type is not `void`.  If there is none, the compiler automatically adds `return 0;`